# Call jquery function and send query to server by one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", "User",}))
{     
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)   
           <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
        }
}
```

Can I call jquery function if I click on submit?

**UPDATE**

```
 $('form').on('submit', function () {
            someFunction();
        });

        function someFunction() {
            alert("Check");
        }
```

This scrip doesnt call.After submit method in controller is called

Comment: Yes.... see below answer

Comment: And I can call this script and call method Update?

Comment: You can call whatever method is in scope, if you have an Update() method then yes you can

Comment: @AdamJeffers I write script but it doesnt call

Comment: Can you show me your script?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following...

***EDIT:***

**HTML**

```
<input id="update" type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
```

**JS**

```
$('#update').on('click', function(){
    someFunction()
});

function someFunction()
{
     console.log('called someFunction()');
}
```

If you right click, click 'inspect element', click 'Console' tab at top, look at output.

... and make sure you have included jQuery.

Comment: I can replace 'form' on selector by id?

Comment: Tag: $('form') or Class: $('.update') or ID: $('#update')